# Set points as the point type with Gnuplot (using Aquaterm)

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a problem using gnuplot and Aquaterm as the terminal. 
I have to plot some data using the point as the datamarker.

I know that the marker type is given by the  `linetype` command followed by a number, however when I used the `test` command, the image I've got was the following:

[image]

It seems that  Gnuplot cannot have a style that uses points.

Comment: Please provide more information and clarify the question.

Comment: `plot ... with points` or `plot ... with dots`?

Comment: @user8153: A plot with points, the dots have an only (and tiny) size.

Comment: @Ugnius Malūkas: I'm really sorry if the question wasn't clear. I'm not able to plot a function using my data, setting the marker as a point: I obtain only cross, square, "stars" or "triangle" symbol. I obtain these different marker by writing `plot "data.csv" u 1:2 with points pt #`, where the "#" represents a number (for example the number '1' gives the cross marker) and changing it I obtain different _symbols_, but not the point. When I say "point" I mean a little filled circle , as the one you can obtain by default using MatLab or other programs.

Comment: It seems that this is a known issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/support-requests/212/, apparently without a fix for now. Is there any particular reason you're using aquaterm? I'd suggest wxt, which is much more flexible, and would allow you to plot points as needed.

Comment: @Vinicius Placco: Aquaterm was recommended by our teacher for Mac users. However I'll will follow your advice and install wxt. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can plot your data with circles that are filled in aquaterm. First, set a few items:

```
set style circle radius .02
set style fill solid
plot 'YourDataFile' with circles lc 'red'
```

Now these markers will scale according to your x axis so change the radius to whatever is appropriate for you.